# .fadeOut() behaving like .fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply trying to fade in an element (#topNav) on scroll when the user is scrolling down and then when the user scrolls back up and hits the scrollTop, fade it out.
Fade in on scroll down; fade out on scroll up.

But, it is fading in on both directions?

What am I doing wrong?

```
function scrollFunc(e) {
    if ( typeof scrollFunc.x == 'undefined' ) {
        scrollFunc.x=window.pageXOffset;
        scrollFunc.y=window.pageYOffset;
    }
    var diffX=scrollFunc.x-window.pageXOffset;
    var diffY=scrollFunc.y-window.pageYOffset;

    if(diffX<0){
        // Scroll right
    }
    else if(diffX>0){
        // Scroll left
    }
    else if(diffY<0){
                    // scroll down
        $('#topNav').fadeIn();
    }
    else if(diffY>0){
        // Scroll up
        if(document.body.scrollTop === 0){
                            //reached top
            $('#topNav').fadeOut();
        }
    }
    else{
        // First scroll event
        $('#topNav').css('position','fixed').show().fadeIn();
    }
    scrollFunc.x=window.pageXOffset;
    scrollFunc.y=window.pageYOffset;
}
window.onscroll=scrollFunc;
```

Comment: can you put your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: I would throw console.log in your diffX/Y checks, I'm thinking the values aren't coming out as you expect.

Comment: I've already done that, see the initial commit of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3mce/), js line 8 @Kal_Torak

Comment: Yeah it's what I suspected, I'm sometimes ending with a 0,0 output,  which it counts as a first scroll event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue as I was trying to achieve the same thing. This depends on jQuery, however. I assume that you have jQuery linked already as you are using the fade functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()>0){
            $("#topNav").fadeIn();
        }
        else{
            $("#topNav").fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3mce/1/) and it worked, so I guess it maybe a version issue.
What's your jQuery version and the browser?

`//some code required by SO`

Comment: I just ran the fiddle, and it seemed to work, but after going up and down a couple times, the box would fadeOut when I started going back up,  then when I reached the top again, it would fade in.  FF20.0

Comment: Weird, I just scrolled up and down dozens of times, using the latest Chrome, and everythings' fine. @Kal_Torak

Comment: I'm using the latest chrome and jQuery 1.9